# What's a benefit between passing a serialized object in a session and unserialized one?

Tags: php, session, serialization

Let's say we have index.php that has something like

```
$randomObj = new rndObject;
$_SESSION['object'] = $randomObj;
```

and securePage.php will have

```
$whatever = $_SESSION['object'];
```

vs

```
$randomObj = new rndObject;
$_SESSION['object'] = serialize($randomObj);
```

and securePage.php will have

```
$whatever = unserialize($_SESSION['object']);
```

I have tried both and it seems to have same results. So is there a benefit to serializing an object when passing it to a session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass an object to session, the object will be serialized by default. And you can implement the __sleep() method if you want to do some customize.

Comment: Let's say it was not automatically serialized, what would happen?

Comment: Your object would be gone. Because of the new page request.